# How do I set up my @product=Product.find(params[:id]) to have a product_url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to recreate { script/generate scaffold }, and I've gotten thru a number of Rails basics. I suspect that I need to configure default product url somewhere. But where do I do this?

**Setup:**

1. Have: *def edit { @product=Product.find(params[:id]) }*
2. Have *edit.html.erb*, with an edit form posting to *action => :create*
3. Have *def create { ... }*, with the code redirect_to(@product, ...)
4. Getting error: **undefined method `product_url' for #< ProductsController:0x56102b0>**

**My def update:**

```
def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        format.html { redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Product was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: [edit] ohh, it's you who answered the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, add in /config/routes.rb the line:

```
map.resources :products
```

and make sure you put that above the default:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

This defines a system for giving :product's urls.